# Finding files using find and brace expansion

Tags: bash

I am trying to trying to `find` some scripts in bash.

```
FOLDERS='one,two'
eval find "{$FOLDERS}/*.sh"
```

Of course I want to do this without eval. But removing eval simply gives:

```
find: {one,two}/*.sh: No such file or directory
```

How can I make `find` accept a variable set of folders using something like brace expansion, and without using a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Use an array, then you can expand the array elements directly.

```
folders=(one two)
find "${folders[@]}" -name '*.sh'
```

The nice thing about this is it'll work even if the folders have whitespace, commas, or other special characters.

```
folders=('comma,separated,name' 'My Documents')
```

Answer (score 1):

A working command using brace expansion would look like:

```
$ find {one,two} -name "*.sh"
```

Demonstration:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir {one,two}
$ touch {one,two}/{a.sh,b.sh,c.txt}
$ ls one/
a.sh    b.sh    c.txt
$ ls two/
a.sh    b.sh    c.txt
$ find {one,two} -name "*.sh"
one/b.sh
one/a.sh
two/b.sh
two/a.sh
```